Spring-boot / Docker make actuator accessible at the root before the context
I've been struggling for a while to find a solution to the following problem:
I have a SpringBoot web application running in a Docker container.
The context is not at the root, it is of type:
server.servlet.context-path = /context-path/

Only, I am asked that actuator be accessible at the root therefore:
server-address/actuator/** should work.

And the web app must continue to run on its context:
server-address/context-path/**

For security and network reasons in production I am obliged to keep the "context-path". I can't just put the application path at the root.
I'm considering redirecting requests like server-address/actuator/** to server-address/context-path/actuator/**
I can't find a way to do this in the application because everything is behind the context path. Is it possible to do this upstream in the Docker container?

Have you tried spring.mvc.servlet.path instead of server.servlet.context-path. If that doesn't work run the management information on a different port.

Yes i try it it doesn't work

Then run the actuator on a different port that way you can differentiate the path. At least this will work without manually reconfiguring a lot of the infrastructure.
